# JSoup, remove text from HTML which has no tags

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have HTML code with that kind of content:

```
<div>
   <div><!-- There is useful content --></div>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   THIS IS SAMPLE TEXT
   <br>
   THIS IS SAMPLE TEXT 2
</div>
```

I need to remove `THIS IS SAMPLE TEXT` and `THIS IS SAMPLE TEXT 2`.

I know how to remove text inside specific tag, but when I try to set text of root div to empty string, all other useful tags will also disappear.

How to remove text without tags inside root tag, not affecting other tags?

Comment: Did you mean to put </div> instead of <div> after "There is useful content"?

Comment: @HansBrende I have fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Element myOuterDiv = myDocument.select("div").first();

for (TextNode textNode : myOuterDiv.textNodes()) {
    textNode.remove();
}

System.out.println(myOuterDiv);
```

Which prints:

```
<div>
 <div>
  <!-- There is useful content -->
 </div>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
</div>
```